# How to set background Image for different state of WKInterfaceButton?

Tags: swift, watchkit

I want to set the backgound image for different state of WKInterfaceButton using Swift. I'm already tried to search on Google but no luck. Anyone know? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By reading the Apple's documentation of WKInterfaceButton, I think you just can't set a specific image for a state of the button because there actually no states at all. Just 'enabled' or 'disabled'.

If you're looking to change the image depending on that, I recommend you to set it directly after setting the 'enable' property of the button. (Maybe by subclassing/extending the WKInterfaceButton, adding two images to it "enabledImg" and "disabledImg" and setting the correct one to its background in the "setEnable" method)